# How to add multiple location in onesignal segment Editor

Tags: react-native, push-notification, onesignal

I am trying to add multiple location in segment editor of one signal.
Can someone let me know how can it do it?

[image: This is how it is]

Please let me know how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, you can (see the image below) yo can `add filter` for `AND` or `add OR filter` for `OR`

[image]

Comment: i have 50000 location points , how can i add them

Comment: You should use OneSignal REST API to do this

Comment: was my answer helpful? Did you manage to do this?